# Self-Hosted Sentry event retention not working as expected

Tags: sentry

We are updating Sentry from 9.1.2 to the latest version and want to keep all issues. After following all the hard stops 9.1.2 -> 21.1.0 -> 21.5.0 -> 21.6.3 -> 23.6.2 -> latest and setting SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS=3650 in .env during the update from 9.1.2 to 21.1.0, the Sentry update script correctly processes all issues, which then go into the ClickHouse table sentry_local. When counting the table, it appears that all are in there, but they cannot be selected from the WebUI, only with 90 days back (the default value of SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS). From 21.1.0 -> 21.5.0 again with SENTRY_EVENT_RETENTION_DAYS=3650 in .env, the events migrate from table sentry_local to table discover_local, but only those with 90 days back and so until the latest. Is there a way to keep all issues, it has also been tried to remove the sentry-cleanup cron as written in the README ("If you do not want the cleanup cron, you can remove the sentry-cleanup service from the docker-compose.yml file.") the result is the same - you see events only with 90 days back.

All issues are available and can be selected back through the WebUI, not just those from 90 days ago.